# How to use functools.partial for a class method?

Tags: python, class, object, partial, functools

I'd like to apply partial from functools to a class method.

```
from functools import partial

class A:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def process(self, constant):
        self.result = self.i * constant

CONST = 2
FUNC = partial(A.process, CONST)
```

When I try:

```
FUNC(A(4))
```

I got this error:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'i'
```

It seems like CONST has been exchange with the object A.

Comment: That's because `CONST` is passed to `self`, not `constant`.  `.process()` is an instance method

Answer (score 4):

You're binding one *positional* argument with `partial` which will go to the first argument of `process`, `self`. When you then call it you're passing `A(4)` as the second positional argument, `constant`. In other words, the order of arguments is messed up. You need to bind `CONST` to `constant` explicitly:

```
FUNC = partial(A.process, constant=CONST)
```

Alternatively this would do the same thing:

```
FUNC = lambda self: A.process(self, CONST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a partial from an *instance* of `A`.

```py
CONST = 2
a = A()
FUNC = partial(a.process, CONST)
```

You can then call `FUNC` like so:

```py
FUNC(A(4))
```